# Using WebServiceTempalate with keystore trusted with multiple certificates

Tags: java, spring, web-services, keystore, apache-httpcomponents

I am using Spring WebServiceTemplate to consume a SOAP based web service and HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender as message sender. I have trust store having multiple certs trusted. I need to connect different hosts based on the client input. I am using DestinationProvider to achieve that instead of default URI.

Following is the configuration.

```
    @Bean(name = "sessionTemplate")
    public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() throws Exception {
        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
        webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(sessionCreatejaxb2Marshaller());
        webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(sessionCreatejaxb2Marshaller());
        webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(swsSessionHttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender());
        webServiceTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        System.out.println(webServiceTemplate.toString());
        return webServiceTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender swsSessionHttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender() throws Exception {
        HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender httpsUrlConnectionMessageSender = new HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender();
        httpsUrlConnectionMessageSender.setTrustManagers(sessionTrustManagersFactoryBean().getObject());
        return httpsUrlConnectionMessageSender;
    }

    @Bean
    public KeyStoreFactoryBean sessionTrustStore() {
        KeyStoreFactoryBean keyStoreFactoryBean = new KeyStoreFactoryBean();
        keyStoreFactoryBean.setLocation(trustStore);
        keyStoreFactoryBean.setPassword(trustStorePassword.trim());
        return keyStoreFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public TrustManagersFactoryBean sessionTrustManagersFactoryBean() {
        TrustManagersFactoryBean trustManagersFactoryBean = new TrustManagersFactoryBean();
        trustManagersFactoryBean.setKeyStore(sessionTrustStore().getObject());

        return trustManagersFactoryBean;
    }
```

I have verified that there are two trusted certs for Host A and B in the trust store which is used. I am using destination provider in following way,

```
    if ("A".equalsIgnoreCase(environment))
        sessionTemplate.setDestinationProvider(destinationProviderA);
    else if("B".equalsIgnoreCase(environment))
        sessionTemplate.setDestinationProvider(destinationProviderB);
    ResponseAndHeader responseAndHeader = swsSessionTemplate.sendAndReceive(new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
```

And so on.

When I try to hit this service from my test passing A and B randomly, I am getting following exception once in 6 to 7 times,

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:561)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:539)
at com.aa.ct.cs.session.controller.SwsSessionController.executeSessionCreateRequest(SwsSessionController.java:79)
at com.aa.ct.cs.session.SessionClient.getSwsToken(SessionClient.java:19)
at com.aa.ct.cs.session.SessionClientTest.testSWSSessionCreate(SessionClientTest.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection.getRequestOutputStream(HttpUrlConnection.java:89)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractSenderConnection$RequestTransportOutputStream.createOutputStream(AbstractSenderConnection.java:87)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.TransportOutputStream.getOutputStream(TransportOutputStream.java:41)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.TransportOutputStream.write(TransportOutputStream.java:64)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.writeTo(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.writeTo(SaajSoapMessage.java:277)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:46)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:658)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:606)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
... 33 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 56 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
... 62 more
```

I have Even tried with HttpComponentsMessageSender as message sender but it is resulting the same.

Please let me know if I am missing anything here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out that one of the intermediate certificate in the chain is missing. Adding that solved the problem.